# Angular 2 Block-scoped Variable Issues

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-decorators

I am currently running an Angular 2 demo using TypeScript. There are two files: the index.html file that is being imported as a template and the TypeScript file. The TypeScript file compiles to a ***pomodoro-timer.js*** and for this demo, all of the classes are contained in one file:

***pomodoro-timer.ts***

```
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    Pipe,
    PipeTransform,
    Directive,
    OnInit,
    HostListener
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

/// Model interface 
interface Task {
    name: string;
    deadline: Date;
    queued: boolean;
    pomodorosRequired: number;
}

/// Local Data Service
class TaskService {
    public taskStore: Array<Task> = [];

constructor() {
    const tasks = [
        {
            name: "Code an HTML Table",
            deadline: "Jun 23 2015",
            pomodorosRequired: 1
        },
        {
           name: "Sketch a wireframe for the new homepage",
           deadline: "Jun 24 2016",
           pomodorosRequired: 2
        },
        {
            name: "Style table with Bootstrap styles",
            deadline: "Jun 25 2016",
            pomodorosRequired: 1
        },
        {
            name: "Reinforce SEO with custom sitemap.xml",
            deadline: "Jun 26 2016",
            pomodorosRequired: 3
        }
    ];

    this.taskStore = tasks.map(task => {
        return {
            name: task.name,
            deadline: new Date(task.deadline),
            queued: false,
            pomodorosRequired: task.pomodorosRequired
        };
    });
}

/// Component classes 

/// - Main Parent Component

@Component({
    selector: 'pomodoro-tasks',
    styleUrls: ['pomodoro-tasks.css'],
    templateUrl: 'pomodoro-tasks.html'
})

class TasksComponent {
    today: Date;
    tasks: Task[];

    constructor() {
        const TasksService: TasksService = new TasksService();
        this.tasks = taskService.taskStore;
        this.today = new Date();
    }
};

bootstrap(TasksComponent);
```

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello Angular 2!</title>
        <!-- required stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <!-- required javascripts -->
        <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>

        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            // importation of component module
            // with no file extension
            System.import('built/pomodoro-tasks').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <strong class="navbar-brand">My Pomodoro Tasks</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <pomodoro-tasks></pomodoro-tasks>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, however, this portion of the ***pomodoro-timer.ts*** file seems to be throwing an error:

```
class TasksComponent {
    today: Date;
    tasks: Task[];

    constructor() {
        // (Cannot find name 'TasksService'.at line 91 col 29, BELOW)
        // (Block-scoped variable 'TasksService' used before its declaration.at line 91 col 48, BELOW)
        const TasksService: TasksService = new TasksService();

        // (Cannot find name 'taskService'.at line 92 col 22, BELOW)
        this.tasks = taskService.taskStore;
        this.today = new Date();
    }
};

bootstrap(TasksComponent);
```

Anyone familiar with TypeScript have any idea why I would be getting those errors? I am using Atom IDE with TypeScript plug-in.

Comment: `TasksService !== TaskService`

Comment: I didn't notice that. Our new demo was using naming conventions we picked up from Angular2 API documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)First you have a typo `taskService` instead of `tasksService`

2)You shouldn't instantiate TasksService as you have done here.

```
constructor() {
  const TasksService: TasksService = new TasksService();
  this.tasks = taskService.taskStore;
  this.today = new Date();
}
```

You should rather change the code to this

```
constructor(private taskService:TasksService) {
  this.tasks = this.taskService.taskStore;
  this.today = new Date();
}
```

To learn more about dependency injection and best practices check this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Comment: Thank you. While I didn't have to change the parameter format in order to get it working, it appears our demo wasn't abiding by the casing rules of Constructors (like classes) vs. variables. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

If you initialize object like this

```
const TasksService: TasksService = new TasksService();
```

you will receive below error,

```
Blocked-scoped variable 'TasksService' used before its declaration.
```

To resolve this issue, change the name of your variable to something else like

```
const TaskServ: TasksService = new TasksService();
```

> **NOTE:** This error usually comes when you declare a variable with the same name as of class(Object).